# pandas apply custom function on subset of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe:

```
A  B  C  v1  v2  v3
q  2  3  4   9   1
8  f  2  7   4   7
```

I want to calc a new columns, that will have the RMS `(sqrt(sum(x^2))` of all the v columns.
So the new df will be:

```
A  B  C  v1  v2  v3 v_rms
q  2  3  4   9   1   9.9
8  f  2  7   2   4   8.3
```

since `sqrt(4^2 + 9^2 + 1^2) = 9.9, sqrt(7^2 + 2^2 + 4^2) = 8.3`

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for `v` columns, then [`DataFrame.pow`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html) with `sum` and for `sqrt` is used `pow` with `1/2`:

```
df['v_rms'] = df.filter(like='v').pow(2).sum(axis=1).pow(1/2)
print (df)
   A  B  C  v1  v2  v3     v_rms
0  q  2  3   4   9   1  9.899495
1  8  f  2   7   2   4  8.306624
```